# Stylesheet for cytoscape does not take affect. Text and graph does not show correctly

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I am trying to create a following graph using cytoscape.

https://pathwaycommons.github.io/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/

I have installed cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet and cytoscape as dependency on my angular app.

Here is the code for the angular app

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as cytoscape from 'cytoscape';
import sbgnStylesheet from 'cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('cy') el: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    var cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'), // container to render in
      stylesheet: sbgnStylesheet(cytoscape),
      elements :[]  //copied from https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/blob/master/demo.json
      layout: {
        name: 'preset',
      },
    });
  }
}

Html File
```

```

But I do not see the actual styles of the graph and I do not see any labels as well. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the picture that I see with no styling of nodes and no labels

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the node/edge JSON structure?

Comment: @StephanT.  Sure. I copied it from the following link: https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet/blob/master/demo.json

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd just be guessing whats wrong. Can you provide a working example of your problem?

Comment: @StephanT. This is the complete working example. You can check it on the following link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-brkwkv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debugging took way too long, but the mistake was quite small, just use this:

`style: sbgnStylesheet(cytoscape),`

instead of:

`stylesheet: sbgnStylesheet(cytoscape),`

This is an error on the [cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet](https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet) repositories README, the [Usage](https://github.com/PathwayCommons/cytoscape-sbgn-stylesheet#usage) passage clearly states to use "stylesheet", though the demo uses "style" as per usual.

Here is the revised version of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7mtr7?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: That worked! I just wanted to know what is the easiest way to calculate x and y position of the nodes if I am creating something from scratch? @Stephan T.

Comment: Also is there is documentation on different classes and styles that sbgn stylesheet provides? Like in JSON there is bbox but there is no documentation for that

Comment: Glad I could help. For your question: What do you want to do with the preset layout? Do you already have the node/edge structure ready to go? If so, you may want to manually align them and use the ```ele.jsons()``` function to return the nodes with their current x and y.

Comment: What do you mean by manually align them? I have a data lineage image(jpeg) that I am trying to create in cytoscape. Is there a desktop software where I can create the graph?

Comment: The classes are defined by the SBGN Standard, there is a reference card [here](https://sbgn.github.io/learning) with the different classes used by the cytoscape-sbgn extension.

Comment: You can use cytoscape [desktop](https://cytoscape.org/) and create the graph there i suppose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228226/discussion-between-learn-aspnet-and-stephan-t).